# Problems with a minipage into tikzpicture in a beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, minipage

I'm writing a presentation and I have a problem with minipages into tikz presentation.

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
    \node (lemma) at (9.5cm,1.2cm) [lemma] {
            \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}\scriptsize\\
            
            $\ $\\
            \noindent\textbf{Lemma.} This is a lemma
            \[Math\]
            End of the lemma\\
            
            \end{minipage}
    };
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}
```

I can't compile it. The error is "Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{frame}". I don't know what is happening here, and i can't found nothing similar.

**EDIT** I'm using this kind of lemma because i want to put in a exact position.
in order to do something like this:
[image]
The minimal code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{lemma} = [rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, line width=2pt,fill=black,fill opacity=.45,text opacity=1]
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
        \node (lemma) at (9.5cm,1.2cm) [lemma] {
            \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}\scriptsize\\
            
            $\ $\\
            \noindent\textbf{Lemma.} This is a lemma
            \[Math\]
            End of the lemma\\
            
            \end{minipage}
        };
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on the site, please post a full minimal example including documentclass (`beamer`) and a limited preamble. BTW why make your own? beamer some with lemma support

Comment: Unlearn the use of ``\\`` in the text, the error you get is `there is no line to end here`, removing those ``\\`` removes those errors. Next you forgot to define `processcolor2`, after defining that as well the example works

Comment: @daleif this is not the problem, because if I comment everything in the minipage the error is the same. The color i forgot to introduce it in the code, but you can replace it by black

Comment: Just remove the `\\ ` after `\scriptsize`.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for comment. This compiles for me on TeXLive 2020. I just removed the `\\`'s and the irrelevant `$\ $\\`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{lemma} = [rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, line width=2pt,fill=black,fill opacity=.45,text opacity=1]
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
        \node (lemma) at (9.5cm,1.2cm) [lemma] {
            \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}\scriptsize

            \noindent\textbf{Lemma.} This is a lemma
            \[Math\]
            End of the lemma

            \end{minipage}
        };
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's a problem of my computer, your code doesn't copiles but in other one yes. Tank you